# Shouldn't REST API be presentation layer of database?

Tags: database, rest, api

If you want to launch REST API you create backend app. 
Client connects with backend, that connects with database, then it responds to backend, that responds to client. Wouldn't that be a great save of effort if database implemented REST API as a presentation layer?

Of course that is a lot of work, but isn't REST API the most popular communication "standard" that needs standarization?

Answer (score 3):

In someway that is happening. Of course, when you come to real world application some problems starts to happen and you need to be flexible enough so the developer can do whatever it wants without compromising the security of the application.

What you said is so true that, in some way, there are already SaaS that can be considered a database with REST access (or something similar).

To list some:
1. https://restdb.io/
2. https://firebase.google.com

There are also some libraries that can help you leveraging any database with rest interface:

1. https://www.progress.com/blogs/restify-databases-expose-your-database-to-rest-web-services
2. https://www.slashdb.com/
3. https://github.com/formio/resquel

This is just an opinion, perhaps your question should be turned into a wiki or something.

Comment: [answer] recommends not answering questions that "solicit opinions rather than facts" in the first place.